# Spring Fox Swagger - Is there a way to add documentation for APIs that are not part of the project

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

The back end of our project is made with spring and we document the APIs with spring fox swagger. We have two APIs in the engine that we want to document on the same page. Is there a way to do that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add custom JSON file. [Spring Fox Documentation](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#aggregating-multiple-swagger-specifications-in-the-same-swagger-ui)